# Microsoft Access function not working

Tags: ms-access

I have this function and it works except instead of displaying the inches 11.25 it displays only 11.

```
Function InchesToFtIn(varInches As Variant) As String

   Dim intFeet As Integer
   Dim intInch1 As Integer
   Dim intInch2 As Single
   Dim strReturn As String

   strReturn = ""
   intFeet = 0
   intInch1 = 0
   intInch2 = 0

   intInch1 = Val(Nz(varInches, 0))
   intFeet = intInch1 \ 12
   intInch2 = ((intInch1 / 12) - intFeet) * 12

   strReturn = intFeet & "'" & intInch2 & Chr(34)
   InchesToFtIn = strReturn

End Function
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Because you are defining inches as integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce it using `Mod` to:

```
Public Function InchesToFtIn(varInches As Variant) As String

    Dim intInches   As Integer
    Dim strReturn   As String

    If IsNumeric(varInches) Then
        intInches = Val(varInches)
        strReturn = intInches \ 12 & "'" & intInches Mod 12 & """"
    End If

    InchesToFtIn = strReturn

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
intInch2 = ((intInch1 / 12) - intFeet) * 12
```

to

```
intInch2 = intInch1 - (intFeet * 12)
```